# How can i restrict the user to save file only in the given folder path in a qfildialog and prevent him to browse in other location?

Tags: python, pyside2, qfiledialog

As described in the title, i want to save a file in a specific location using qfiledialog. I can do that by put the path in the options of the qfiledialog, and it works fine. But here the user can browse in other locations, i don`t want him to do that. Can you help me ?

```
    options = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.Options()
    options |= QtWidgets.QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
    fileName, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(
            None,
            "Save file",
            os.path.join(PATH, "filename"),
            "XML (*.xml)",
            options=options)

    if fileName:
            with open(fileName, "w") as f:
                f.write(doc.toprettyxml())
```

Comment: The purpose of your question is clear but the restrictions are not. For example, would it be valid to delete the widgets that allow browsing or do you want that even when using those widget, it still remains in the same folder?

Comment: Delete the widgets that allow browsing. Thank you